# DecimalFormat not formatting my numbers correctly

Tags: java, android, math, decimalformat

I want to round all of my numbers to 1 decimal place.

For example

```
22.0
-6.1
```

I am using:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
middlePanelTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(score.getElevationAngle()));
```

But whole numbers don't have a 0 appended to it.

```
-18 should be -18.0 etc.
```

instead my value shows up as `-18.`

Comment: Any chance that `middlePanelTextView` cuts the text? Does it display -18.5 correctly? Additionally, could you try this: `DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH));`

Comment: What value type does the method `score.getElevationAngle()` return?

Comment: `score.getElevationAngle()` returns a double

Comment: For me your code works perfectly and returns -18.0 when giving a value -18 to it.

Comment: Sheehan Alam:) It's working exactly as liro says. I have tested it. There should be some other mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My TextView was cutting off the digits. My fault. Shrank font size.

Answer (score 1):

.@ represents a significant digit 0 doesn't.
.# represents and optional digit So try "##@.@"

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

I'm not sure about the syntax: but the above article should give you all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
middlePanelTextView.setText(""+decimalFormat.format(score.getElevationAngle()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```

as the constructor parameter instead.

Comment: Please read the OP again, he wants to get the zero, so # is the wrong pattern here.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0#");
```